# Using AutoResetEvent multiple times

Tags: c#, .net

I have two asynchronous calls to one web service in .Net 4.0 C# application.  These are controlled by using AutoResetEvent `WaitOne()`.

In my local machine this is working as expected. But when I deployed it in a server, the success handler of second step is called in the first call.

What change need to be done to have the thread behave properly?

```
if (userID != null)
{
    AddressBookRequest req = new AddressBookRequest
    {
        contactsSearchCriteria = new ContactsSearchCriteria
        {
            searchUserID = userID.Trim()
        },
        HeaderParams = new HttpHeaderParms
        {
            UserId = userID.Trim(),
            UserPrincipalName = userID.Trim() ,
            ContentType = "application/xml"
        }
    };
    lookupServicesAssociate.SearchContactDetailsAsync(req);
    autoRestEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    lookupServicesAssociate.SearchContactDetailsCompleted +=
        new EventHandler<ServiceResponseEventArgs<ContactDetailsPreview[]>>(AssociateSearchContactDetailsCompleted);
    autoRestEvent.WaitOne();
}

if (reportsToUserID != null)
{
    AddressBookRequest req1 = new AddressBookRequest
    {
        contactsSearchCriteria = new ContactsSearchCriteria
        {
            searchUserID = reportsToUserID.Trim()
        },
        HeaderParams = new HttpHeaderParms
        {
            UserId = reportsToUserID.Trim(),
            UserPrincipalName = reportsToUserID.Trim(), 
            ContentType = "application/xml"
        }
    };
    lookupServiceReports.SearchContactDetailsAsync(req1);
    lookupServiceReports.SearchContactDetailsCompleted +=
        new EventHandler<ServiceResponseEventArgs<ContactDetailsPreview[]>>(ReportsToAssociateSearchContactDetailsCompleted);
    autoRestEvent.WaitOne();
}
```

Comment: What does "the success handler of second step is called in the first call" mean? What is the scope of `autoRestEvent` and what code is calling its `Set` method? If you wait for the calls to the web service to return, why are you calling them asynchronously?

Comment: @Igor autoRestEvent is in the class level. `Set` is called by success handlers. It is an existing asynchronous service. I have no control on the service

Comment: Are conditions and test data on server the same as on your local machine? Maybe I'm missing something, but it looks OK and the only reason why `ReportsToAssociateSearchContactDetailsCompleted` would be called first is - the first `if` statement returned `false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading your code correctly, you have a dangerous race condition. You have:

```
lookupServicesAssociate.SearchContactDetailsAsync(req);
autoRestEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
lookupServicesAssociate.SearchContactDetailsCompleted +=
    new EventHandler<ServiceResponseEventArgs<ContactDetailsPreview[]>>(AssociateSearchContactDetailsCompleted);
autoRestEvent.WaitOne();
```

In the first line, you call the async method. Then, you create the `AutoResetEvent` and assign the event handler.

If `SearchContactDetailsAsync` were to complete before you assigned the callback, your `WaitOne` would never complete because the callback wouldn't be executed and the event would never be signaled.

You really should write:

```
autoRestEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
lookupServicesAssociate.SearchContactDetailsCompleted +=
    new EventHandler<ServiceResponseEventArgs<ContactDetailsPreview[]>>(AssociateSearchContactDetailsCompleted);
lookupServicesAssociate.SearchContactDetailsAsync(req);
autoRestEvent.WaitOne();
```

Although to be perfectly honest, I wonder why you'd start an async task and then just wait on its completion. You're effectively doing it synchronously.

All that said, I have to agree with Pako's comment: this can't happen unless `UserID == null`. Which raises another potential problem: if `autoResetEvent` is `null` and `UserID == null`,  the second `WaitOne` is going to throw `NullReferenceException`. And if multiple threads are executing this code, each one is going to create a different `AutoResetEvent`, which will then for sure cause problems because you could end up waiting on an event that won't ever be signaled, or waiting on the wrong event and capturing somebody else's signal.